# Implement task groups for Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

My Kafka topic have multiple consumers. I want to implement a system such that I can assign a Id to several tasks and based on that ID they can only be consumed by the same consumer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put record keys into your data and they will be sent to the same topic partition. When consuming,  one consumer of the consumer group will be assigned that partition to read